# Is this proof of a nonincreasing sequence correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm given that $a_{2n} = 1/n$, $a_{2n+1} = a_{2n}$, and $a_1$ = 1, and am told to prove that $a_n$ is nonincreasing.

I recognize that to prove that the sequence is nonincreasing, I have to show that $a_{k+1} \leq a_k$ for all $k > 0$.

I identify three cases: $k = 1$, $k>1$ and odd, $k$ is even. (It's an integer greater than zero, so all these should make sense.)

In the case where $k$ is even, I say that there exists an integer $n > 0$ such that $2n = k$.

$a_{2n} = a_{k}$,

$a_{2n+1} = a_{k+1}$

$a_{2n} = 1/n = a_{2n+1}$. Therefore $a_{k+1} = a_{k}$.

In the case where $k$ is odd and greater than 1, I say that there exists an integer $n > 0$ such that $2n+1 = k$.

$a_{2n+1} = a_{2n} = a_{k} = 1/n$,

$a_{2n+2} = a_{2(n+1)} = a_{k+1} = 1/(n+1)$

$a_{k+1} = 1/(n+1) < a_k = 1/n$ (since n > 0).

In the case where $k = 1$,

$a_k = 1$ and $a_{k+1} = a_2 = 1/1 = 1$ so $a_k = a_{k+1}$.

Therefore in all cases, $a_{k+1} \leq a_k$

Is this proof correct and sufficient? It feels sort of awkward to do the odd/even split.

Comment: Yeah you're proof is perfect. No mistakes. The even-odd split is necessary to handle such sequences.

Comment: It is fine. What you call the third case is already covered by the second, where we can allow $k=1$.

Comment: It is correct and sufficient

Comment: Wouldn't the second case involve a division by zero for $k = 1$?

Comment: @Aniket sorry , just a small note, we say your and not you're !! :P

Comment: @Nizar Well it was a typo. When I realised it,it was well past the $5$ min mark. So couldn't edit it. Anyway, thanks for noticing it :-)